# How to get private inner class instance with reflection in Java?

Tags: java, reflection

```
public class OuterClass {
    private static class InnerClass {
        public int id = 0;
    }
    private static InnerClass[] innerArr;
}
```

Need to get innerArr value with reflection in Java.

```
ClassLoader loader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
Class<?> cla = loader.loadClass("OuterClass");
Field innerArrRef = cla.getDeclaredField("innerArr");
innerArrRef.setAccessible(true);    
OuterClass.InnerClass[] innerArrValue = (OuterClass.InnerClass[])innerArrRef.get(cla);
```

Above code doesn't work for InnerClass is a private class.

Comment: Post what you have tried as an [mcve] and describe where you are having problems.

Comment: It's a bad idea to give the name `InnerClass` to a member type declared `private static class InnerClass` because by definition in Java an inner class is a member class that is not declared `static`. This makes the name "`Inner`-anything" very misleading for a static nested type. (It's​ also a bad idea to put the redundant word `Class` in the name of a class.)

Answer (score 3):

Let's adjust your `OuterClass` code a bit to make it more interesting: put in instance of `InnerClass` in the array:

```
private static InnerClass[] innerArr = { new InnerClass() };
```

Now you can't directly refer to the private type `InnerClass` in another class that is trying to get the static field using reflection. You can first refer to it as an array of Object.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Class<?> cla = OuterClass.class;
    Field innerArrRef = cla.getDeclaredField("innerArr");
    innerArrRef.setAccessible(true);
    Object[] innerArrValue = (Object[]) innerArrRef.get(cla);
```

You'll need to use reflection and the `Class` object to use the InnerClas type.

One way is to use the `declaredClasses` property of the `OuterClass`' class object:

```
    Class<?> inner = cla.getDeclaredClasses()[0];
```

But if there's more than one member class, you need to loop through the array and search for the right one. Another way is to use the knowledge that javac will give your InnerClass a fully-qualified type name that looks like `mypackage.OuterClass$InnerClass`:

```
    Class<?> inner = cla.getClassLoader().loadClass(cla.getName() + "$InnerClass");
```

Once you have the class object of the InnerClass, you can use reflection to access its field and methods:

```
    Field id = inner.getField("id");
    System.out.println("Inner id: " + id.getInt(innerArrValue[0]));
}
```